# how to extract href attribute of ‘a’ element using id= instead of class name

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have the following:

```
<div id="header-author" class="some random class">
        <a id="author-text" class="some random class" href="/page?id=232">
          <span class="some random class">
            Hello there
          </span>
        </a>
```

and i want to extract only href attributes of id="author-text"
i cant use class to extract because the class is used by other elements which has href links which i do not want to extract

i have tried this

```
soupeddata = BeautifulSoup(my_html_code, "html.parser")
my_data = soupeddata.find_all("a", id= "author-text")
for x in my_data:
    my_href = x.get("href")
    print(my_href)
```

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer!

Comment: What output are you getting using the code you tried? Syntactically it is correct.

Comment: just saw i was getting tab error and you;re right my code works fine just fixed the tab error and its working :p :D btw mahesh's code is also working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
my_data = soupeddata.find_all('a', attrs = {'id': 'author-text'})
```

You can also pass `class` attribute inside the dict.

From the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> Some attributes, like the data-* attributes in HTML 5, have names that
>   can’t be used as the names of keyword arguments:
>
> ```
> data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>') 
> data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value") 
> # SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
> ```
>
> You  can  use  these  attributes  in  searches  by  putting  them 
>   into  a  dictionary  and  passing  the dictionary into find_all() as
>   the attrs argument:
>
> ```
> data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"}) 
> # [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
> ```

Comment: Thanks bhai <3 worked like a charm and got what i wanted thanks for the help.